# Addressing items within nth-of-type

Tags: html, css, firefox

My HTML is something like this:

```
<div class="entry">
  <div class="imageContain">
    <img src="photo1">
  </div>
  <div class="title">Blah</div>
  <div class="text">Whatever</div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="imageContain">
    <img src="photo2">
  </div>
  <div class="title">Foo</div>
  <div class="text">Some stuff</div>
</div>
```

I want to style the `imageContain` in every alternate `entry` div differently.

In Chrome, this works:

```
.entry:nth-of-type(odd) {
  .imageContain {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

but Firefox seems to ignore it

Both Chrome and Firefox ignore this:

```
.entry:nth-of-type(odd).imageContain {
  background-color: red;
}
```

How can I address the `imageContain` divs inside alternate `entry` divs, please?

Comment: Like all pseudo-classes, `nth-of-type` selects elements. not classes of elements, and by adding a class to it, you effectively make it act like a filter for the elements its matching. What you seem to be after is something like `nth-of-class` which doesn't exist

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a space:

`.entry:nth-of-type(odd) .imageContain`

About you original code:

```
.entry:nth-of-type(odd) {
  .imageContain {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

It is currently not supported for all browsers.
https://caniuse.com/css-nesting

Here when was added to Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/whats-new-css-ui-2023/#nesting

The space works because it is the "descendant" selector. Here is the list of all selectors
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php

***Update*** You probably see this type of code structure on systems like:
CSS Preprocessors - Sass or Less

Comment: Thank you. It seems the first version in your answer is supported by most desktop browsers, and that happens to be all I care about for this. If you have time to explain why it works, or tell me how I could have arrived at that answer, I'd be grateful, because I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps, I added some more context to the answer

Comment: I also added context about Sass and Less that probably is where you see this code before.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the second CSS selector doesn't work is because it's trying to select both the `.entry:nth-of-type(odd)` and `.imageContain` elements at the same time.

To get the desired functionality, you can use the following CSS selector:

```
.entry:nth-of-type(odd) > .imageContain {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This selector will select all .imageContain elements that are children of .entry elements that have an odd nth-of-type value.